# Android WebView does not render iframe content in Chrome 78

Tags: android, webview, chromium, nestedscrollview

We have an html content with an iframe, loaded inside a webview. When using chrome version 78, the content will render the first paragraphs at fist and then at a certain height will display blank and sometimes distorted text up until the bottom part.

To reproduce, place a webview inside a scrollview and load a content containing iframe tags, the webview wont load all of the content.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_logo" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Some distorted result looks like these:
[image: webview bug]

Comment: Why are you using NestedScrollView? You can remove this scrollview parent and try WebView directly in your layout.

Comment: @SudheeshR actually theres more inside the scrollview since we also display headers with the webview being the content. edited the question

Comment: Ok, update your question with the webview settings you are using to load the url.